# How to signup auth0 users to flutter app using custom UI?

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, auth0

I want to add auth0 authentication to my flutter app but when I checked their docs and searched everywhere they show their auth0 ui but I want to use my custom UI for authentication. I have a express backend with auth0 how can I authenticate or signup user using the express server.

I tried reading their docs but in the docs they show authentication only for login but I want to create user using my flutter frontend using my own custom UI

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package,

`https://pub.dev/packages/auth0/versions/2.2.0-beta1`

https://pub.dev/packages/auth0/versions/2.2.0-beta1

This package is based on Auth0 REST APIs. You will able to build custom UIs using it.

Or,

You can make use of Auth0 REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for but from where do I know what payload I have to send for creating a user?

Comment: https://github.com/mishatron/flutter_auth0/blob/master/lib/data/auth0_client.dart#L191